# How to prevent Visual Studio Code Flutter/Dart Editor from formatting new line/wrapping code?

Tags: flutter, dart, format, visual-studio-code

I recently started working on Flutter/Dart, I like the flutter autoformatting on-save, but one thing might or might not be related is the code wrapping for long code even if code is still fitting my 4k editor window.

Is there a way to prevent new line but keep the comma auto format?

Thanks

[image: example of code auto formatted to new line]

[image: .vscode/settings.sjon]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Follow the instructions below:

1. Open `Settings`.
2. Expand `Extensions` and click `Dart & Flutter` on the left.
3. Find `Dart: Line Length`.
4. Change it to the value you want.

[image]

Comment: Finally, a lifesaver! It's actually a dart setting instead of a vs code setting.

Comment: You might also want to change the value of parameter "editor.rulers" in settings.json, in the "[dart]" section, in order to have the corresponding ruler displayed in the editor.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Android Studio? `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Dart > Line length` only moves the vertical guide. Dart still breaks the line after 80 chars. I also tried adding `- lines_longer_than_80_chars` to the rules in `analysis_options.yaml` as suggested [here](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/lines_longer_than_80_chars#:~:text=Avoid%20lines%20longer%20than%2080,available%20as%20of%20Dart%202.0.)